# Read SSH Config file and login to server using Node-JS npm library

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh

I am able to connect to EC2 instances through git-bash/Putty when I run below command:
ssh host-name
.This works because in ssh/config file all the parameters are present.
My requirement is to do the same using Node-js npm library. is there way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a npm package available. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh

When you create your EC2 instance (e.g. ubuntu server) you can download your private key file `yourprivatekey.pem` which you need for authentication.
Create a new node project and run `npm i node-ssh`. Copy `yourprivatekey.pem` in project folder and change the file permission `chmod 400 yourprivatekey.pem`.
Create a `index.js` file in the project folder and paste the following example code with a ssh copy command, to copy a file from EC2 to your local machine.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const {NodeSSH} = require('node-ssh')
 
const ssh = new NodeSSH()
 
ssh.connect({
  host: 'abc123456-example.compute-1.amazonaws.com', //replace with your ec2 host
  username: 'ubuntu', //replace with your EC2 username
  privateKey: './yourprivatekey.pem' //replace with your private key file
})
.then(function() {
  // Local, Remote (replace with you own file path)
  ssh.getFile('/home/pi/test.txt', '/home/ubuntu/test.txt').then(function(Contents) {
    console.log("The File's contents were successfully downloaded")
  }, function(error) {
    console.log("Something's wrong")
    console.log(error)
  })
})
```

Other ssh operations see in API Documentation at the link above.

Comment: i have checked this before as well but not able to understand the uses here. Could you please place couple of line, where you want me to refer.

Comment: No, this is not going to work because, I am trying to connect to private server via bastion host. This npm doesn't support bastion host. That's why I was looking for some npm library, which can read my ssh/config file.

Comment: do you want to set up a ssh server or a ssh client?